# Linq To Sql - Dynamic

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have two Tables:

> Table 1: Client
>
> Fields: Id_Client Char 5 Name_Client
>   Char 50
>
> Table 2: Country
>
> Fields: Id_Country Char 4 Name_Country
>   Char 80 Population Int 15

With Sql I can make this 2 queries

> Select Id_Client, Name_Client from
>   Client
>
> Select Id_Country, Name_Country,
>   Population from Country

I wan to do this 2 queries in only one using Linq SQL.
I think something like this

> string Option = "";
>
> string SelectFields = ""; string
>   TableName = "";
>
> if (Option == "Client"){
>
> ```
>    SelectFields = "Id_Client, Name_Client";
>    TableName = "Client";
> ```
>
> } 
>   else{
>
> ```
>    SelectFields = "Id_Country, Name_Country, Population";
>    TableName = "Country";
> ```
>
> }
>
> Select "SelectFields" from "TableName"

**I'm a Visual Fox Pro Developer and using Evaluate (macros) this is very easy to do. Is possible to do something like this on Linq To Sql???**

Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into dynamic linq to sql, this will allow you to pass in the expression as a string.

In the end you will end up with something like the following:

`IQueryable<SomeItem> = results = context.SomeItem.Where("SomeItemID > 30 AND SomeItemID < 40");`

Additional Information, [Using Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: I saw that, but is very poor, i cant do something really dynamic. You cant use 1 "query" with 2 or more tables.
Any other idea??. Please

Thanks.

Sorry for my poor English